# What is the preferred way to set environment variables at emacs initialization?

Tags: emacs, environment-variables, elisp

For instance, suppose I want to modify my `PATH` variable in my .emacs file.  What is the best way to do this?  Should I call `setenv`?  Is there a variable I can customize?  Should I call a shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it right:

```
(setenv "PATH" "some;/path/that/you/want;/really/this/is/the/path")
```

The bigger question is, why do you want the path to be different just inside Emacs?  Is it to tell Emacs to find the appropriate applications for `ispell` or `shell`?  There are more straight forward ways to solve those problems.

Comment: I actually want to control which Python pymacs runs under.  It would really be cool to be able to run a virtualenv for that.

Comment: One thing to note:  in the above example, PATH should be in double quotes.